# Why do most dragon slayers in Fairy Tail have their emblems on their shoulder?

Tags: fairy-tail

I wanted to know why their emblems are on their shoulder. I realized it days ago. If any of you have any answers or theories, please tell me. I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I assume it's only a design choice from the author. As far as I remember, the emblem is put wherever the user wants to put it.

Answer (score 2):

@Jerry is right, the placement of the guild's symbol is *wherever the mage wants it*. If you remember in **Volume 1 Chapter 2**, Mirajane was asking Lucy if she was sure she wants the symbol placed on her hand, *implying that mages have a choice as to where they can put it*.

As to how some dragon slayers have their guild's symbol in their shoulders, that is mostly coincidental and if there was any special meaning to it, *it was not focused upon nor explained throughout the series*, at least in the manga, if I recall correctly.